# Sublime Text 2 context highlighting for FAME

Tags: sublimetext2, syntax-highlighting

This is probably a shot in the dark considering how obscure the [FAME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FAME_%28database%29) programming language is, but is anyone familiar with an already extant FAME language definition/syntax file for Sublime?

Comment: my guess is since emacs has FAME highlighting, one could easily be created, but I don't know of any offhand in the wild